# onClick event failing

Tags: javascript, xhtml

My function is:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Info popup window
function showInfo(infFilename) {
alert(infFilename);
popupWin = window.open('notes/"+infFilename+"','open_window','width=400,height=300,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=20,top=20' );
}
</script>
</head>
```

The php code calling the popup is:

```
<?php>
// check if metadata exists ( PicNotes is "filename.php" )
if ($row['PicNotes']) {
$icon = "<img src = \"images/info.png\"  onClick=\"showInfo($row[PicNotes])\" />";
}else{
$icon='';}

echo "<a href='images/".$row['vfile']."' rel='enlargeimage' rev='targetdiv:loadarea' title='&lt;b&gt;".$row['Title']."&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br /&gt;".$row['Medium']." &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ".$row['iw']." x ".$row['ih']." cm. $icon'><img border='1' src='images/".$row['tnfile']." ' alt=' '  width='".$row['tnx']."' height='".$row['tny']."' class='tn' /></a><br />";

?>
```

The html of this line is (from view source):

```
<a href='images/0712120189y.jpg' rel='enlargeimage' rev='targetdiv:loadarea' title='&lt;b&gt;Broken Bridge in Water Meadow&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Gouache &amp; Pastel &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 24 x 19 cm. <img src = "images/info.png"  onClick="showInfo(wm_series.php)" />'><img border='1' src='images/0712120189z.jpg ' alt=' '  width='96' height='75' class='tn' /></a>
```

Please can somebody see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `showInfo('wm_series.php')` needs quotes around the name.

Comment: Take a look at the HTML of the `<img` element. You're missing quotes around the argument to `showInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
onClick=\"showInfo($row[PicNotes])\"
```

should be:

```
onClick=\"showInfo('$row[PicNotes]')\"
```

You need quotes around the filename argument, since it's a string.

Also, you have an characters here:

```
cm. $icon'>
```

It should be:

```
cm. $icon
```

Your popup code should be:

```
function showInfo(infFilename) {
    alert(infFilename);
    popupWin = window.open('notes/'+infFilename,'open_window','width=400,height=300,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=20,top=20' );
}
```

Comment: Thenks Barmar but I have already tried that but is stops php processing the line properly. The output becomes:<br /> `<a href='images/0712120189y.jpg' rel='enlargeimage' rev='targetdiv:loadarea' title='&lt;b&gt;Broken Bridge in Water Meadow&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Gouache &amp; Pastel &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 24 x 19 cm. <img src = "images/info.png"  onClick="showInfo('wm_series.php')" />'><img border='1' src='images/0712120189z.jpg ' alt=' '  width='96' height='75' class='tn' /></a>`

Comment: double quotes and escaping them produce the same result.

Comment: You can't use double quotes because you're already using double quotes around the `onclick` attribute itself. HTML attributes don't support escaping, although I think you could use `&quot;` in it. But single quotes should work as I wrote it. They're the opposite quotes from the ones used around the attribute, so there's no conflict.

Comment: It's not rendering correctly the view source display is all red and the closing end tag is rendered as text.

Comment: Just tried &quot: the onclick statement then renders as onClick="showInfo(&quot;wm_series.php&quot;)" but the popup still doesn't fire

Comment: Make the second fix I posted in my answer, I think that solve the syntax problem you had.

Comment: Hi Barmar - onClick=\"showInfo(&#39;$row[PicNotes]&#39;)\" seems to work but the popup code seems to have an error the url is rendered as /notes/"+infFilename+"

Comment: You had bad quoting in `showInfo`, too. I've added the fix to my answer.